# generate uncorrelated number in the C language using rand()

Tags: c, random

I want to generate uncorrelated random number to do a simulation... However, the numbers generated by the `rand()` function in the `C language` are correlated. 
Is there any possibility to use the `rand()` function and generate multiple random streams?
 I mean, if the `rand()` function generate for me a series of correlated numbers, can I cut this series into different streams. Then use these streams independently?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by correlated? The random numbers from rand() are not correlated in much sense. However they are pseudo-random, and they will follow a sequence, and the sequence will eventually repeat itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed correct. They are normally autocorrelated as the normal generator implementation is *linear congruential* (although the C standard does not mandate this). As such an x-y plot of successive numbers will fail a chi square test for random 2D dispersion.

Depending on your application, you could look at *Bays-Durham* shuffle which, to my knowledge, passes the *diehard* test for randomness: it's aim is to defeat autocorrelation effects.

I direct you to www.nr.com for an implementation and the `rand1`, `rand2` functions in particular. A more modern way is to use a *mersenne twister* scheme but a little tricker to implement (by the way C++11 has this generator as part of its standard library).

Comment: Is the Bays-Durham shuffle can be implemented in the C language. Sorry I didn't get it..

Comment: Yes. www.nr.com is "numerical recipes in C". They have the algorithm.

Comment: Sorry still didn't get it. So, shall I import a library to embed specific function do for me the work. Or, I have implement something by myself..

Comment: You just need to copy the function. It's only about 20 lines long.

Comment: MT19937 could be found here: http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/CODES/mt19937ar.c

Comment: Hi again, 
@Aean  so I have to copy the this entire code into my program code, then use genrand_int32 function instead of rand()?

Comment: @Dhoha use `init_genrand` instead of `srand`, `genrand_int32` will return a random number in range [0x00000000, 0xFFFFFFFF], and `genrand_int31` will return [0x00000000, 0x7FFFFFFF].

Answer (score 1):

If your C implementation has **rand_r**, you can try that. It lets you specify a location to store the state.

Or just use your own pseudo-random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `arc4random` or better `ar4random_uniform` to increase randomness of generated values (actually `ar4random_uniform` proves you uniformly distributed values).

Answer (score 0):

Generating true random numbers on a computer is impossible, you can only generate "pseudo-random" numbers i.e. numbers that "looks like" random.

Usually one will use a ''seed'' (small sequence of bits) with enough entropy and then "expand" it thanks to a [Pseudo-Random-Number-Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

C `rand()` function generates poor quality of randomness, try PRNG that have been proposed in other answers/comments. Some [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pseudorandom_number_generators):

- [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) (widely used)
- [ANSI X9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) (adopted by FIPS standard)